# How to add 1 nano second to a timestamp

Tags: ibm-db2

How to add 1 nano second to a timestamp.

I am doing this -

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + '0000-00-00 00:00:01' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

but it does not help me.

Can anyone please help me in this ?

Comment: `'0000-00-00 00:00:01'` is not a nanosecond but a second